# How to return 2 json objects at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rest

I have a controller returning a json structure like so:

```
def show
  # .......
  o_json = deep_object_1_to_json(o)
  render :json => o_json
end

private
def deep_object_1_to_json(o)
  o.to_json(
    :include => {....})
end
```

Now I need to extend it to return 2 objects. However the obvious solution is giving me problems:

```
def show
  # .......
  o1_json = deep_object_1_to_json(o)
  o2_json = deep_object_2_to_json(o)
  render :json => 
  {
         :object_1 => o1_json,
         :object_2 => o2_json
  }
end
```

This returns a json object with 2 strings of escaped json data!

The deep_object_2_to_json functions already have several layers of nested includes so I would rather not have to refactor these into a single function. Is there a way to make this easily extendable to add more objects in the future without the double escaping problem above?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you should be constructing something upon which `to_json` can easily be called.

The obvious candidate for active record objects is `as_json`. This does everything that `to_json` does (include the `:include` option and so on) except actually turning the object into json. Instead you get back a ruby hash which you can manipulate as you want and then call to_json. For example you could do

```
render :json => {
  :o1 => object1.as_json(:include => :blah),
  :o2 => object2.as_json(:include => :blah)
}
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about as_json. Looks like my deep_objects_to_json methods can be changed to deep_objects_as_json and then I can call to_json once at render time as benzando suggested. Thank you!

Comment: Nice, I forgot about `as_json`. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

If you can refactor your class to return it's JSON via the `to_json` method, you can simply stick two or more objects into an array and call `to_json` on the array:

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > require 'json'
 => true 
1.9.3-p125 :002 > [{foo: "bar"}, {bar: "foo"}].to_json
 => "[{\"foo\":\"bar\"},{\"bar\":\"foo\"}]"
```

Example:

```
def to_json
  super(include: [:some_association])
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure this this is possible. If my object "foo" is an active record object, that has many "bars", each with a "baz" etc etc. And I want these to all be serialized, then AFAIK I have to call to_json on each independently with the necessary includes.

Comment: You can call the includes in your to_json implementation. I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller shouldn't be serializing the object as JSON until right before it hands it off to be rendered.

In other words `deep_object_1_to_json` should just be `deep_object_1`. Then you can package both return values into an array or hash and render the as JSON.

```
def show
  # .......
  o1 = deep_object_1(o)
  o2 = deep_object_2(o)
  render :json =>
  {
         :object_1 => o1,
         :object_2 => o2
  }
end
```

It might be a pain to change it now, but for the future of your system, you really ought to be doing it this way. JSON is just a format for sending objects over the wire or to disk; none of your code should have any references whatsoever to JSON unless it is passing it off to be rendered.

Comment: OK, this makes sense, do you know what is the best way to obtain an in memory version of an active record object that will render all the required nested assocations when to_json is invoked?